# Magento 2: Add quantity 2 when add to cart from product view page

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

Add quantity 2 when adding to cart from product view page.

For only one product because it calls a 2-time post request for one product.

After clearing cache and checking and some time that works, but again that problem comes in other product.

Comment: Have you customize anything or extended any js ?

Comment: have you got this answer @user15917

Answer (score 0):

The `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add::execute()` method has support for the `qty` request param. Try adding a new hidden input named `qty` and a  value of `2` in the add-to-cart form template file.

Maybe there's a more elegant way of doing this, but I don't know about it yet.

Comment: I have added this code:
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            },
            "catalogAddToCart": 
            {
    "addToCartButtonTextDefault": "<?php echo __('Add to Cart'); ?>",
    "addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding": "<?php echo __('Adding...'); ?>",
    "addToCartButtonTextAdded": "<?php echo __('Added'); ?>"
   }
        }
    }
</script>

in  vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Answer (score 0):

from addtocart.phtml

```
<input type="number" 
    name="qty" 
    id="qty" 
    maxlength="12" 
    value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
    class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"  />
```

change value to "2"

Answer (score 0):

Hello it happen with me.

Solution for that:addtocart intilize two times on page so find out and remove it

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the built in functionality within magento for **Minimum Qty Allowed in the Shopping Cart** just make sure you set **Enable Qty Increments** and set the **Qty Increments** value this should give the customer a notification prior to adding to the shopping cart thus preventing the need for adding to cart multiple times.